# Highcharts - plot xAxis Bands where value is below 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

my goal is to plot x-Axis bands like someone did here:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w3htb4g1/

```
xAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
        color: '#e6f4e4',
        from: 0,
        to: 2.5
      }]
}
```

But I want to position them automatically where the line value is below 0, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/smaica/vsfLwoxt/1/

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Btw: Im using highcharts stock charts in a React frontend (javascript).

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to know what the bands are and supply that to highcharts. Highcharts typically is data agnostic, it will display what you give it in the way you say you need it to display, it does not make any assumptions beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Duniyadnd comment I calculated the first and last index where the data crosses the y-Axis and then push the plotBands like so:

```
var plotBand = []
for (var i = 1; i < crossings.length; i++) {
    if(i%2!=0){
        plotBand.push({from: crossings[i-1], to: crossings[i], color: color})
    }
}
```